# How to restore data on database when only have the .frm files and ibdata1

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, innodb, myisam

I have the data from an old MYSQL server but it's only contain `.frm` files without `.myd` and `.myi` or `.ibd` files and the outside database folder there some data file like ibdata1.

I've been googling for how to recovery it, try it but not successful and now I'm stuck. Could somebody suggest me how to restore my data? Thank you for your help

Comment: You're likely out of luck. Typically InnoDB data is stored in `.ibd` files. Unless your data is stored in the ibdata1 file (old tables created when `innodb_file_per_table=OFF` was in effect are stored all together in that system tablespace). Sorry!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yeah I know, but lucky me by using XAMPP now my database restored as what I expect. happy me.

Comment: Feel free to write up how you did it as an answer to your own question, so you can help people who find this post later.

Comment: Sure, thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply by using `XAMPP` I can restore the database back as what I expect only with `.frm` files and ibdata1.

Here is the experiment:

1. Installing `XAMPP` in this case using `XAMPP v3.2.1`
2. Open drive (in this case drive C:) then search `xampp` folder
3. Find the `mysql` folder
4. Copy your old database that only contain `.frm` files and your ibdata1 to `data` folder inside `mysql` folder
5. Start your mysql server then check your database, your data is back!

NOTE: When you already install `XAMPP` on your computer, you must **stop mysql**  first before copying the old database